# Array inside Struct wont copy correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Was wondering if anyone could help me with this, I have this struct in my code

```
struct Gate {
  int output[9];
};
```

And i had a vector of that struct, but pushing to the vector which normally would create a copy broke because its only a shallow copy, and my struct has an array
so I tried to work around this by creating a custom copy constructor.

```
struct Gate {
    int output[9];
    Gate(const Gate &old){
        copy(old.output, old.output + 9, output);
    }
};
```

but now my initializers dont work anymore, because they are trying to use this copy constructor

```
Gate alwaysFirst{{0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2}};
Gate alwaysSecond{{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2}};
```

```
universal_gate_finder.cpp:39:41: error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const Gate&'
   39 |     Gate alwaysFirst{{0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2}};
      |
```

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Comment: I'm confident that objects of this type will copy correctly without the need for an explicit copy constructor. What exactly led you to believe that this is not the case?

Comment: "_pushing to the vector which normally would create a copy broke because its only a shallow copy_" - what more would that `struct` require? The default copy constructor would copy `output` just fine.

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/1PWdJSG4
I am creating the Gate objects on line 53, and copying them to the vector at line 62 and 67. I check on line 58 to make sure that none of the array values are greater than 2 for any reason. And on line 55 I check if its still less than 2, the error im getting is on line 55, implying that the values are changing after I copy them to the vector.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] here.

Comment: Unless I did something else wrong (probably between lines 49 and 57, I believe the error is memory related.

Comment: Yeah, you have [`heap-use-after-free`](https://godbolt.org/z/hjsKPfzex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Gate alwaysFirst{{0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2}};
Gate alwaysSecond{{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2}};
```

These lines use *aggregate initialization*, which is only possible on *aggregates*, which cannot have user-declared constructors.

By declaring a custom copy constructor, your type is not aggregate anymore.

You can replace the aggregate initialization with a `std::initializer_list` constructor or a constructor taking an array by reference, both of which would re-enable that syntax (more or less).

However, it is unnecessary to declare the copy constructor. The implicit copy constructor already constructs the array member from the source object by element-wise copy construction.

Your replacement instead uses copy-assignment which has no benefit over directly copy-constructing the elements.

Declaring a copy constructor also disables the implicit move constructor, which is an additional pessimization.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I did not know this. In this case do you know why my arrays werent copying correctly with the default constructor, I listed the details in a comment to my initial post.

Also, how exactly would an initalizer_list constructor look, im having trouble finding anything online.

Comment: @ConorOMalley You should post a minimal reproducible example _in the question itself_. The problem in your code has nothing to do with the array member of `Gate`. But now it is a bit late, since there is already an answer to your unrelated question.

Comment: @ConorOMalley Inserting elements into a vector invalidates all iterators, pointers and references to elements of the vector. So it is a bad idea to do that while iterating over the vector.

Comment: Bro thank you so much you are a genius, thats what it was, my a pointer was being messed up cause I was pushing stuff to that same vector, appreciate it man.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `struct Gate { std::array<int, 9> output; };`?
[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/3b7PnG6sM)

Comment: I still get the same error described in the comment to my post, where all of a sudden one of the elements in the array is some crazy high number

Comment: Ok, I saw your link in the comments of your post. Stop using pointers. Use a `std::bitset` for the `bool[]` and `std::array` instead of C-style arrays.  
You can then set the bits in the bitset using `set(getHash(alwaysFirst))` where `getHash` is `static std::size_t getHash(std::array<int, 9> const&) noexcept;`. Yes, you're probably dereferencing some out of bound memory, no I can't tell you where it happens.